# getter 'uid' was called on null, receiver null on flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i am trying to create mobile app with flutter and connect it to firebase.

i created register vendor function

```
Future<UserCredential> registerVendor(email, password) async {
UserCredential userCredential;
try {
  userCredential =
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    email: email,
    password: password,
  );
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
  if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
    this.error = 'The password provided is too weak.';
    notifyListeners();
    print('The password provided is too weak.');
  } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
    this.error = 'The account already exists for that email.';
    notifyListeners();
    print('The account already exists for that email.');
  }
} catch (e) {
  this.error = e.toString();
  notifyListeners();
  print(e);
}
return userCredential;

}

 /// save vendor data to firestore
 Future<void> saveVendorDataToDb(
  {String url,
  String shopName,
  String mobile_number,
  String email,
  String location,
  String desc})async {
  User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  DocumentReference _vendors = 
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vendors').doc(user.uid);
    _vendors.set({
    'shopName': shopName,
    'mobile': mobile_number,
    'email': email,
    'location': location,
    'description': desc,
    'shopOpen': true,
    'rating': 0.00,
    'totalRating': 0,
    'isTopPicked': true,
  });
  return null;
}
```

and this is the code for mobile app

```
   FlatButton(
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                onPressed: () {
                  if (_authData.isPicAvail == true) {
                    if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
                      _authData
                          .registerVendor(email,
                              password)
                          .then((credential) {
                          uploadFile(_authData.image.path).then((url) {
                            if (url != null) {
                              _authData.saveVendorDataToDb(
                                url: url,
                                shopName: _shopNameTextController.text,
                                mobile_number: _mobilePhoneTextController.text,
                                email: _emailTextController.text,
                                location: _locationTextController.text,
                                desc: _descriptionTextController.text,
                              ).then((value) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    _formKey.currentState.reset();
                                  });
                                  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, HomeScreen.id);
                              });

                            }else{
                              scaffoldMessenge('Failed to upload shop profile picture');
                            }
                          });
                      });
                    }
                  } else {
                    scaffoldMessenge("Shop profile picture is needed");
                  }
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Register',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                )),
```

i got error message that said

E/flutter ( 8684): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 8684): Tried calling: uid
E/flutter ( 8684): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:63:5)
E/flutter ( 8684): #1      AuthProvider.saveVendorDataToDb

can anyone help me to solve this problem?

thank you

Comment: User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser; user is null I guess.so this is throwing error DocumentReference _vendors = 
   FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vendors').doc(user.uid);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mofidul comments, it seems like `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser` is `null` which then leads to a problem when you call `user.uid` in this code:

```
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
DocumentReference _vendors = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vendors').doc(user.uid);
```

The solution is always the same: since this code assumes that there is a user signed in, what do you want the app to do when there's no user signed in?

---

If you want to skip saving the vendor data in that case, you can add an `if` check for that:

```
 /// save vendor data to firestore
 Future<void> saveVendorDataToDb(
  {String url,
  String shopName,
  String mobile_number,
  String email,
  String location,
  String desc})async {
    User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user != null) { //  Add this check
      DocumentReference _vendors = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('vendors').doc(user.uid);
      _vendors.set({
        ...
      });
    }
    return null;
}
```

---

You may also only want the user to be able to click on the <kbd>Register</kbd> button in your app when they're registered. In that case, you'll want to put a similar condition in your `build` method, only rendering the `FlatButton` if `user != null`.